# Aggregate function checking 'if contains'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have data:

```
Code   Page     Task
    2   1   Activity
    2   2   Activity
    2   3   Activity Symbols
    2   4   Activity Symbols
    2   5   Activity Symbols
    2   12  Activity
    2   12  Activity Symbols
    2   999 Consider
    2   999 Constituents
    2   999 Material
    2   999 Material Hazards
    316 999 Constituents
    356 999 Constituents
    398 999 Constituents
    604 70  Activity Symbols
    604 999 Constituents
```

I want to group by `Code` and for each check if any of the records in that group contain a `Page` of '999', if so return 'True'.  Is there an aggregate function that will do this?  Or perhaps there is a better way to structure a query like this?

Comment: Do you just want the groups that contain a 'Page' of 999, or do you want all groups and a boolean flag?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
select code,
max(case when page = '999' then 1 else 0 end) as has999
from table
group by code
```

Comment: Ah yes that's what I was wanting, I didn't think to use max